# Nonsense word generator php

Tags: php, random, generator

Do anybody know function or class.
which will generate nonsense words in php
I dont need to get random line from the file which contains a list of words!

---

Example

http://www.mygengen.com/gengens/view/nonsense-words

Comment: Does it need to be PHP?  Would a javascript solution work?  Fixie.js could be very easily adapted to this, and would be much more responsive than a trip back to the server. Depends somewhat on the size of your "nonsense" word list though.

Comment: Just sit a junior developer in front of VI and let him type something

Comment: Seems that downvoting answers on unclosed question has become the new trend. This happens more often than not lately.. if you see no no reason for us to be here, just close our account and you can get rid of us!

Comment: The two answers on this question are off-topic so it's normal they've been downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code in order to generate a random string of characters:

```
<?php

function getRandomString($length = 6) {
            $validCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuxyvwzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUXYVWZ+-*#&@!?";
            $validCharNumber = strlen($validCharacters);

            $result = "";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $index = mt_rand(0, $validCharNumber - 1);
                $result .= $validCharacters[$index];
            }

            return $result;
        }

        $randomString = getRandomString();

        echo $randomString;

?>
```

Remember to tweak the $length and $validCharacters variables.

Comment: The string should be pronounceable, but it doesn't meant to be valid English word

Comment: Then you should compile a list of words and use a function like this one, but with $validCharacters = "1234567890"; to select a random line and echo the word. There is no way to make php echo out a "pronounceable but nonsenseful" word.

Comment: Stating that there would be no way is rather ignorant. You just need to figure out the right way.

Comment: Actually, stating that there would be no way is the right thing to say in this case. It's funny that you dug this up to comment something like that - in this particular case, the user is requesting something that is **programmatically unachievable**.

The **only** way to do this (yay I figured the right way out) is to compile a list of "pronounceable, not necessarily valid English words"(see OP's comment) and create a function to echo them at random order.

I'll be patiently waiting for your reply, I'm sure the way you'll find to defend your point of view will be rather hilarious.

Comment: There's no way to tell what will be programmatically achievable in let's say 5 years.